# Is there any way to send Outlook meeting requests from a non-default calendar?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, outlook, outlook-2007, calendar

We have a user with two Outlook accounts. user@abc.com is of type Exchange; user@xyz.com is of type IMAP/SMTP. Both are actually on our Exchange server; but since an Outlook profile can only have one Exchange account, the second one is set up as IMAP.

The user would like to send a meeting request from her xyz.com account, so the "from" address appears as user@xyz.com. Unfortunately that doesn't work. If she creates the meeting in her xyz.com calendar, the meeting request still goes out through her Exchange account, user@abc.com. The meeting request "compose message" window has an Account dropdown below the Send button, but this has no effect.

Before she sends the invitation, a warning appears:

"Responses to this meeting request will not be tallied because this meeting is not in your main Calendar folder. Is this OK?"

Is there any workaround for this? We're using Outlook 2007 and Exchange 2003 SP2.

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that while you cannot have a "full" MAPI connection to more than one Exchange mailbox via a single Outlook profile, you can get awfully close by making one mailbox a delegate. Many users find this works better than what you're currently doing. Instructions on how to do this are located [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291626).

Once you have this setup, when the user wishes to send a message (email, meeting invitation, etc) from the secondary mailbox, she must fill in that user in the From field in Outlook which is also explained in the link above. Note that if follow this technique when she sends as the other account those messages will say "From Userabc on behalf of userxyz". If you wish to change that so they just say "From userxyz", you'll need to give userabc Send As permission on the userxyz mailbox. Instructions for doing this are [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125118%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely try this out. We'd need full "send as" permissions, since the recipient shouldn't see abc.com at all - but it sounds like this will do what we want.